# Include soci in cmake on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, soci

I have a `HelloWorld` project in JetBrains CLion and set up `boost` so I can build it fine.

I've managed to build `soci` using `cmake` and `make` with `mingw` outside the `HelloWorld` project.

For boost I used:

```
include(FindBoost)
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem)
```

How do I include the `soci` library in my `cmake`? Is there a similar method for including `soci`? I don't know where to start?

**UPDATE**

A bit further I think.

I added the following to my cmake options:

```
-D CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=D:\Development\Tools\lib\soci-3.2.2\cmake\modules
```

and this to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Soci)
if(${SOCI_FOUND})
  target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${SOCI_LIBRARY} ${SOCI_sqlite3_PLUGIN})
else()
  message(WARNING "SOCI NOT FOUND")
endif()
```

I still get `SOCI NOT FOUND` though but at least the `soci` variables turns up in the `cmake` cache.

Comment: For using `find_package()` directive appropriate `FindXXX.cmake` module should be provided. Some modules are available with `CMake`. So it looks like you need write your own `FindSOCI.cmake` module. P.S. You should use [this existed module](https://github.com/SOCI/soci/blob/master/src/cmake/modules/FindSoci.cmake).

Comment: @Gluttton, `FindSoci` is in D:\Development\Tools\lib\soci-3.2.2\cmake\modules` so that seems to work. Or isn't it? P.S. That's the one I'm using :)

Comment: @Asken I quickly check pointed module and it seems to me it's more targeted Linux/Unix environment with exact path as a hint. After implementing https://github.com/SOCI/soci/issues/394 this issue should be solved I think. But nobody knows when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously very late, but it worked for me:

```
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld soci_core soci_mysql)
```

Comment: Never too late as long as it adds something that helps

Comment: This does basically work with SOCI v4.0.2, but sadly the CMake config files generated by the SOCI build are not portable because they contain absolute hardcoded paths to the backend dependencies (in this case MySQL). I've built SOCI with Oracle support and will end up implementing my own custom find module for both OCI and SOCI.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I shame for my country mates because they provide so crapy CMakeLists.txt for SOCI lib. In order to mitigate they bad works, I wrote following intsturctions how to use SOCI in CMake based projects. I do it on Linux KDE Neon 5.16.5 (based on: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), but on Windows probably you have only fix paths. This probalby will work. I am not 100% sure because I just start my project within I want to use SOCI.

This is obviously very late, but it probably works:
I build and install soci like this:

```
cmake "/home/szyk/!-EnergoKod/!-Libs/3rdparty/soci" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake "/home/szyk/!-EnergoKod/!-Libs/3rdparty/soci" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

I add to my project CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SOCI_SOURCE_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/!-EnergoKod/!-Libs/3rdparty/soci")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${SOCI_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${SOCI_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(Soci)
list(APPEND LIBS ${SOCI_LIBRARY} ${SOCI_sqlite3_PLUGIN})
# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIBS})
```

That is generates good looking output:

```
Soci found: Looking for plugins
    * Plugin mysql not found.
    * Plugin odbc not found.
    * Plugin postgresql not found.
    * Plugin sqlite3 found /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoci_sqlite3.so.
Found Soci: /usr/local/include/soci
```